# Howto update index file after update query in FoxPro dbf

Tags: vb6, foxpro, dbase

I need to update records inside a FoxPro (dBase?) .dbf files. The field I need to update inside the record also have an index. Update the record works fine, but the index is not updated. I'm searching the internet for a few days already without any result yet. Somehow I need to open the index file too, but I don't know how.

I'm building a connection via de Microsoft Visual FoxPro Driver. Here is some VB6(!) code:

```
Dim CNF As ADODB.connection, CNFRS as ADODB.Recordset
Set CNF = New ADODB.connection
CNF.ConnectionString = "Provider=MSDASQL; Driver={Microsoft Visual FoxPro Driver};SourceType=DBF;SourceDB=" & pvApp.General.TableName & ";"
CNF.Open
Set CNFRS = CNF.Execute("UPDATE " & pvApp.General.TableName & " SET SYNC_ID='" & sync_id & "' WHERE PVSYSID='" & PVSYSID & "'")
```

So, the update succeeds, but the index is not updated. Any help is much appreciated.

The OLEDB way:

```
CNF.ConnectionString = "Provider=VFPOLEDB.1;Data Source=C:\DB;Password=;Collating Sequence=MACHINE"
```

Still no luck yet!

Answer (score 2):

Update operations (inserts, updates, deletes) on .DBF tables will always update the compound index (.CDX) file associated with the table automatically - there is no need to explicitly do anything. If there are other index files (.IDX) involved then that's a different story. What exactly is making you think the indexes aren't updated? Could you use the OLEDB driver instead ?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The dbf's are used by an application (PerfectView). That application provide me search funtionality based on the indices. When searching it doesn't find the updated value, which does exist inside the record (I can find it manually!). Also the .cdx file isn't modified. The .mdf is. I've reworked using the VFOLEDB Provider (see first post). Still the same problem. It updates, but not the index.

Comment: Index files manually created using INDEX ON .. TO .. could have any extension, including .mdf (which isn't a usual DBF index file?).

Comment: I'm sorry. That is a typo! The extension is .dbf.

Comment: Does the CDX file have the same name as the DBF? For the update to be automatic, you need to have something like MyTable.DBF and MyTable.CDX. If you do, then the update should be automatic and if it's not, it makes me wonder whether you have a corrupted index.

Answer (score 1):

@netiul: It's can be posible, that your experiments on .dbf files can remove link in .dbf file to .cdx (index) file (link is a one bit in .dbf file). And as result "Visual FoxPro Provider" thinks that your .dbf does not have an associated .cdx file and does not updates it.

Read in MSDN about DBF file structure http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/st4a0s68%28v=vs.80%29.aspx Check for byte offset 28, flag 0x01